# An ice-cream parlour offers 15 different flavours of ice-cream. An ice-cream sundae contains 5 scoops of ice-cream.

Tags: probability

An ice-cream parlour offers 15 different flavours of ice-cream. An ice-cream sundae contains 5 scoops of ice-cream. Suppose someone selects the five scoops
of a sundae at random (repetitions allowed).

What is the probability that  the ice-cream sundae contains exactly 2 scoops of vanilla ice-cream?

I would calculate the number of different ice cream sundaes as following: $15^5$$=$$759375$. Then i would calculate the possible ways of ice cream sundays with two vanilla scoops and divide it by $15^5$.

But i do not know how to calculate possibilities of choosing exactly two scoops of vanilla ice-cream. I am really stuck and would appreciate any help or hint. My guess what have been $15*1*14*14*14$ but it seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the possible choices for each scoop.
$$ 1 * 1 * 14 * 14 * 14$$

Since we want exactly 2 scoops of vanilla.

Now think of how many ways we can get this order.

We multiply by $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$ because there are 5 scoops made up of 2 vanilla and 3 non-vanilla.

Solution = 27440 possibilities.

Comment: After rereading the problem I now wonder why I have assumed that order matters in this problem and I cannot find any legitimate answer except my intuition. Would you mind to help me to understand why order matters here?

Comment: Well the way I see it is the order of the scoops matters because they can be in any order. (e.g. they didn't tell us that the vanilla scoops must be the first and second scoop.) So, we must take into account any possible permutation of 3 non vanilla scoops and 2 vanilla scoops. You can even work this out by hand but the easy way to do it is by multiplying by $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$

Comment: Yeah i also assumed that the order matters by defining my probability space accordingly - i have got it now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose which two of the scoops are vanilla-how many ways?  Then choose each of the other three scoops from among the $14$ non-vanillas.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a binomial random variable:

Let x = # of scoops of ice cream that are vanilla.

Then p = 1/15  and q= 14/15

Then P(x=2) = (1/15)^2*(14/15)^3*(5 C 2) = 0.0361